# Keeping two synched sets of mailboxes

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, sync, mbox, maildir

I have a desktop at work, a desktop at home, and a laptop (all linux). My laptop usually stays in my office, because even though it's light, I don't care to carry useless weight: I have remote ssh access to my desktop and use a versioning system to keep all source files of my homedirs synched on the 3 computers. I have the laptop with me when travelling, of course.

I want to be able to access my e-mail archives in all three situations : at work, at home (online from my desktop), and offline on my laptop when travelling.

At present I have the mail archives on the laptop. But since a recent date, I don't have remote ssh access anymore to my laptop when it is plugged at work. I think the only way out is to have a copy of the mail archives on the desktop at work. What synching solution would you use for this?

Details: mail is stored in maildirs (and a few small mbox-es), about 10 GB at present. I retrieve mail by fetchmail+procmail, and also do some sorting by hand (in mutt). Ideally I would be able to do so on either laptop or work desktop and have at most one command to issue to synch them when bringing in/taking away my laptop to/from work.

Comment: Why not use IMAP? this is after all what IMAP is all about... synched folders maintained on a mail server from which many clients can synch.  I use 2 laptops, 1 desktop, 1 phone and 1 tablet, and because I will diligent with the setup even my deleted and drafts folders are accurate across all devices.

Comment: @Tyson: I'm afraid I'd be over quota on my employer's mailserver, and I don't like to have my e-mail hosted by google or such provider. Then should I turn my desktop at work into an IMAP server?

Comment: To put a server of any type online one of the things you need to consider is whether the upstream bandwidth will support the usage. While I despise gmail and the other "free" email options available, there ARE other pretty low cost paid options available. The difference, with a paid option you don't give up the right to privacy in the TOS.  While I'm not normally a link dropper check out Plan 1 here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans-FX103764022.aspx

Comment: It's pretty much exactly what you want, you just have to get over the fact that your email lives on a server that's secure and is backed up for you.

Comment: @Tyson: I don't think the bandwidth would be an issue as I'd use my desktop as a server only for my own personal usage, or would it? I was more concerned about the technical aspect of this.

Comment: I can't tell you, never done it.  Keep in mind tho that IMAP is a maintained connection that synch's so it's different than the occasional short connections of a web server of file server.